# Twitter bootstrap scrollable table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a table on my website. The problem is that this table will have about 400 lines. How can I limit the table's height, and apply scrollbar to it?
This is my code:

```
<div class="span3">
  <h2>Achievements left</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

  <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

I tried to apply max-height and fixed height to table, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Table elements don't appear to support this directly. Place the table in a div and set the height of the div and set `overflow: auto`.

Comment: Did this actually work? I tried this and it had no effect at all.

Comment: Just FYI, setting overflow to 'auto', rather than overflow:scroll, will not create a redundant horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @NishchitDhanani: You need to wrap the table in a div and set the overflow on the div.

Comment: @JonathanWood: is there a way to apply `overflow` only on the body of the table but where the `<thead>` parts are always displayed?

Comment: only place the <tbody> inside the wrapper div with overflow:auto, instead of the entire table?

Comment: @JonathanWood you will still have the table head and only scroll the body. I would suggest to put a table inside the body of the "parent table" and let only the div inside the body scroll.

Comment: Just to make this clear for people.... <div style="overflow: auto;"><table class="table">....</table></div>

Comment: @cjstehno I got it to work for me by specifying `width: 100%;` on the div as well as the height and `overflow: auto;`

Comment: Please give a small example !

Answer (score 57):

```
.span3 {  
    height: 100px !important;
    overflow: scroll;
}​
```

You'll want to wrap it in it's own div or give that span3 an id of it's own so you don't affect your whole layout.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zm6rf/

Comment: Note that the '!important' isn't important ;)

Comment: Be careful, setting these properties for `.span3` will affect *all* `span3` elements across your entire Bootstrap-driven site.

Comment: I only applied it to specific span3. Is it possible to keep the height relative and still have scroll bar next to the table?

Comment: You can give it a `max-height` instead of a height. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: But that would still make me use pixels. I would like to use percents. Is it possible?

Comment: You can only add a height percentage if the parent container has a pixel height. In your case, you'd need to do something like set .row to 500px and .span3 to 50%. If the parent doesn't have a set height the browser just defaults to the content height if you give it a percent.

Comment: Can you do this while making the tbody scollable and the thead not?

Comment: For your info, setting overflow:scroll will create a horizontal scroll bar which may be redundant. Making it automatic, i.e. overflow:auto, does not do this.

Answer (score 45):

Don't need the wrap it in a div...

**CSS**:

```
tr {
width: 100%;
display: inline-table;
table-layout: fixed;
}

table{
 height:300px;              // <-- Select the height of the table
 display: -moz-groupbox;    // Firefox Bad Effect
}
tbody{
  overflow-y: scroll;      
  height: 200px;            //  <-- Select the height of the body
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/AgI8LpDugl

Comment: I got very excited when I saw this example but it turns out the layout gets "funked up" when the data in the `td` element vary in size. http://www.bootply.com/OsvzINuTUA

Comment: @Frito Don't worry, be happy ;) I just forgot table-layout: fixed; ... Link updated

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue and used a combination of the above solutions (and added a twist of my own). Note that I had to specify column widths to keep them consistent between header and body.

In my solution, the header and footer stay fixed while the body scrolls.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="25%">First Name</th>
                <th width="13%">Last Name</th>
                <th width="25%" class="text-center">Address</th>
                <th width="25%" class="text-center">City</th>
                <th width="4%" class="text-center">State</th>
                <th width="8%" class="text-center">Zip</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="bodycontainer scrollable">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-scrollable">
            <tbody>
                <!-- add rows here, specifying same widths as in header, at least on one row -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
        <tfoot>
            <!-- add your footer here... -->
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

And then just applied the following CSS:

```
.bodycontainer { max-height: 450px; width: 100%; margin: 0; overflow-y: auto; }
.table-scrollable { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks it does help. Unfortunately I cannot specify the width of th elements since it is not a valid element though. (???)

Comment: columns of the td are not aligned with the th elements because the scrollbar shifts the content

Comment: Ahh... I'm on a Mac where the scroll bars are invisible and appear on top of the content only while scrolling. That will be a tough one as scrollbars are os and browser dependent.

Answer (score 10):

CSS

```
.achievements-wrapper { height: 300px; overflow: auto; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="span3 achievements-wrapper">
    <h2>Achievements left</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the height relative?

Comment: I want to have the height set with percents. Is this possible? I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Sure, just set the table height to 100%.  `.table-class-name { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: That extends my table, and it goes on and on. (It has no effect)

Comment: By this method, the header is scrollable as well, so is there a way to fix the table header?

Answer (score 9):

I recently had to do this with bootstrap and angularjs, I created an angularjs directive which solves the problem, you can see a working example and details on this [blog post](http://pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/angularjs-fixed-header-scrollable-table-directive).

You use it just by adding a fixed-header attribute to the table tag:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" fixed-header>
...
</table>
```

If you're not using angularjs you could tweak the directive's javascript and use it directly instead.

Answer (score 6):

Put the table in a div and give that div the class `pre-scrollable`.

Answer (score 4):

All above solutions make table header scroll too...
If you want to scroll tbody only then apply this:

```
tbody {
    height: 100px !important;
    overflow: scroll;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This will only work if its a single column table. If you have a table with multiple columns this will only make the first column scroll.

Answer (score 4):

This is may not a solution for large row count. I simply use duplication table trick to get the thing done for small row count table while it can keep flex column width, you can try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjyuoyrt/).

(The fixed width column is the method I use for large row count table which require only the header row duplication)

Sample Code:

```
<div style="height:30px;overflow:hidden;margin-right:15px;">
   <table class="table">
       <thead>
           <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Cel 1,1</td>
                <td>Cel 1,2</td>
                <td>Cel 1,3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cel 2,1</td>
                <td>Cel 2,2</td>
                <td>Cel 2,3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cel 3,1</td>
                <td>Cel 3,2</td>
                <td>Cel 3,3</td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="height:100px;overflow-y:scroll;;">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Cel 1,1</td>
                <td>Cel 1,2</td>
                <td>Cel 1,3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cel 2,1</td>
                <td>Cel 2,2</td>
                <td>Cel 2,3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cel 3,1</td>
                <td>Cel 3,2</td>
                <td>Cel 3,3</td>
            </tr>
             <tr style="color:white">
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This example shows how to have sticky headers when using Bootstrap 4 table styling.

```css
.table-scrollable {
    /* set the height to enable overflow of the table */
    max-height: 200px;
    
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.table-scrollable thead th {
    border: none;
}

.table-scrollable thead th {
    /* Set header to stick to the top of the container. */
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0px;
    
    /* This is needed otherwise the sticky header will be transparent 
    */
    background-color: white;

    /* Because bootstrap adds `border-collapse: collapse` to the
     * table, the header boarders aren't sticky.
     * So, we need to make some adjustments to cover up the actual
     * header borders and created fake borders instead
     */
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;

    /* This is our fake border (see above comment) */
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #dee2e6,
                inset 0 -1px 0 #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="dashboard-container card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-scrollable">
      <table class="table table-hover table-sortable">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th data-sort-type="text">Course</th>
                  <th data-sort-type="numeric">In Progress</th>
                  <th data-sort-type="numeric">Not Started</th>
                  <th data-sort-type="numeric">Passed</th>
                  <th data-sort-type="numeric">Failed</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>How to be good at stuff</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>1000</td>
              <td>0</td>
              <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Quantum physics for artists</td>
              <td>200</td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>66</td>
              <td>66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>The best way to skin a cat</td>
              <td>34</td>
              <td>16</td>
              <td>200</td>
              <td>7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Human cookbook</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Aristocracy rules</td>
              <td>100</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>18</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The CSS for Bootstrap 5 is much simpler:

Just apply these styles to the first `tr`:

```css
.table-sticky-headers tr:first-child {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: var(--bs-body-bg, white);
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 1px 0 #dee2e6,
        inset 0 -1px 0 #dee2e6;
}
```

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="max-height: 20vh">
    <table class="table table-sticky-headers">
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Message</th>
      </tr>

      <tr><!-- more rows --><td>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note: If you wrap your table header row in `<thead>`, you'll need to adjust the the css selector to `.table-sticky-headers thead`.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar problem and ended up fixing it using a mixture of different solutions.

The first and most simple one was to use two tables, one for the headers and one for the body. This works but the headers and the body columns are not aligned. And, since I wanted to use the auto-size that comes with twitter bootstrap tables I ended up creating a Javascript function that changes the headers when: the body is rendered; the windows is resized; the data in the column changes, etc.

Here is some of the code I used:

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-sort="id">Header 1</i></th>
                <th data-sort="guide">Header 2</th>
                <th data-sort="origin">Header 3</th>
                <th data-sort="supplier">Header 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="bodycontainer scrollable">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-scrollable">
            <tbody id="rows"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The headers and the body are divided in two separate tables. One of them is inside a DIV with the necessary style to generate the vertical scrollbars. Here is the CSS I used:

```
.bodycontainer {
  //height: 200px
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.table-scrollable {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

I commented the height here because I a wanted the table to reach the bottom of the page, whatever the page height might be.

The  data-sort attributes I used in the headers are also used in every td. This way I could get the width and the padding of every td and the width of the row. Using the data-sort attributes I set using CSS the padding and width of each header accordingly and of the header row which is always bigger since it doesn´t have a scrollbar. Here is the function using coffeescript:

```
fixHeaders: =>
  for header, i in @headers
    tdpadding = parseInt(@$("td[data-sort=#{header}]").css('padding'))
    tdwidth = parseInt(@$("td[data-sort=#{header}]").css('width'))
    @$("th[data-sort=#{header}]").css('padding', tdpadding)
    @$("th[data-sort=#{header}]").css('width', tdwidth)
    if (i+1) == @headers.length
      trwidth = @$("td[data-sort=#{header}]").parent().css('width')
      @$("th[data-sort=#{header}]").parent().parent().parent().css('width', trwidth)
      @$('.bodycontainer').css('height', window.innerHeight - ($('html').outerHeight() -@$('.bodycontainer').outerHeight() ) ) unless @collection.length == 0
```

Here I assume that you have an array of the headers called @headers.

It is not pretty but it works. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

None of these answers worked satisfactorily for me. They either didn't fix the table heading row in place or they required fixed column widths to work, and even then tended to have the heading row and body rows misaligned in various browsers.

I recommend biting the bullet and using a proper grid control like [jsGrid](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid) or my personal favorite, [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). It obviously introduces a dependency but if you want your tables to behave like real grids with cross-browser support, this will save you pulling your hair out. It also gives you the option of sorting and resizing columns plus tons of other features if you want them.

Answer (score 2):

Re Jonathan Wood's suggestion.  I don't have the option of wrapping tables with a new div as i'm using a CMS.  Using JQuery here's what i did:

```
$( "table" ).wrap( "<div class='table-overflow'></div>" );
```

This wraps table elements with a new div with the class "table-overflow".

You can then simply add the following definition in your css file:

```
.table-overflow { overflow: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

put the table inside the div to make scrollable table vertically. change `overflow-y`to `overflow-x` to make table scrollable horizontally. just `overflow` to make table scrollable both horizontal and vertical.

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;"> 
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `.table-responsive` to the table and it worked. From the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/)

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table with .table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}, making the table scroll horizontally at each max-width breakpoint of up to (but not including) 576px, 768px, 992px, and 1120px, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I would post on here since I could not get any of the above to work with Bootstrap 4. I found this online and worked perfectly for me...

```json
table
{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border:solid black 1px;
}

thead
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}

tbody
{
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

th, td
{
    width: 100px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I have also attached the working jsfindle.

https://jsfiddle.net/jgngg28t/

Hope it helps someone else.