# Bootstrap responsive table with horizonascroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap 3 `responsive-table` with nearly a hundred columns. Since the number of columns are too many, it does not fit into my computer screen.

According to the bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) on responsive tables, a device/screen with **768px** wide or less will have a horizontal scroll bar for these tables and the rest will not.

Is there a way to make the scroll work even on a laptop/desktop screens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just override the way Bootstrap styles `table-responsive` class by imitating its own CSS. For resolutions lower than 768px, Bootstrap has the following style applied:

```css
/* Bootstrap.css */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    ...

    .table-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
    }
}
```

Therefore, if you want the same behaviour to apply on resolutions larger than 768px, you can simply duplicate this in your own styling:

```
/* Your CSS */
.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

Comment: This works if I display 10 records in a page, but how about a hundred records in a page? The vertical scroll of table doesn't appear

Answer (score 4):

Quick look at bootstrap source shows that code for `table-responsive` looks like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > th,
  .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > th,
  .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > th,
  .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > td,
  .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > td,
  .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered {
    border: 0;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > th,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > th,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > td,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > td {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Just copy everything from `@media` and paste to your css to override bootstrap's, it should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mq2vd3s/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row data-table">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.data-table{width:300px; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y:hidden; }
</style>
```

see here also [Twitter bootstrap scrollable table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420168/twitter-bootstrap-scrollable-table)