# How to show vertical scrollbar for tbody (with bootstrap styles applied on table)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to show vertical scrollbar to `tbody`. Based on my search i have to apply `display:block` on `tbody` and `thead`
like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

However this does not work when i have bootstrap's `table table-condensed` applied on table. The header and content does not align

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5gqck6sk/)

Comment: I think that it's not possible without redefining the "display" property of tbody on css, but that might break the whole table style.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420168

Answer (score 0):

try adding height to .table class

```css
.table { height: 100px }
```